# Aligning three div's next to each other

Tags: html, css-position

I wish to align thee div containers next to each other and I have achieved it, my question now is: Is there a better way of doing it? Or is this way correct.

EDIT:

Another question I have, assume the div's width is not 33.33% but more like 20%, how do I evenly space them out?

fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/robindashwood/fNB5A/

Here is my code, refer to the div's with ID BodyColumn1 to 3.
My code of index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="MainContainer">
        <div id="HeaderContainer">
            <div id="LogoContainter">
                <img class="RoundedImg" src="Images/300x100stock.png">
            </div>
            <div id="NavigatieContainer">
                <ul id="nav">
                <!-- LVL 1 -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="Index.html">Item 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="BannerContainer">
            <img class="RoundedImg" src="Images/1000x400stock.png">
        </div>
        <div id="BodyContainer">
            <div id="BodyColumn1">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <div id="BodyColumn2">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <div id="BodyColumn3">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code of the css handling the layout:

```
/*Basic tags*/
body {
    background-color: #efebdf;
}

/*DIV ID's*/
div#MainContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#HeaderContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div#LogoContainter {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

div#NavigatieContainer {
    float: right;
}

div#BannerContainer {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div#BodyContainer {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

div#BodyColumn1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    background-color: red;
}

div#BodyColumn2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

div#BodyColumn3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    background-color: pink;
}

/*IMG's*/
img.RoundedImg {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Since you have working code and needs review on it, you should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inline-block value for display property

```
div#BodyColumn1 { display: inline-block; width: 33.3%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way to do it and crossbrowser imo.

If you want you can try to do the same with others display properties, or try using the new flexboxes.

Comment: These flex boxes are awesome, thank you for the tip!

Comment: It is, but you shouldn't use it for "real" projects right now, still experimental.